# Excel 2010 VBA runtime Error 462: The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I'm writing to a Word doc from Excel and I will get the 462 error if the macro runs to completion the first time and all Word applications are closed and the macro is rerun. I read good amount of the Microsoft info about unqualified references. I can not figure out what is going at this line to cause an error so I'm hoping someone will be able to find it.

Declarations

```
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Dim i As Integer
Dim titleCount As Long
Dim Count3, Count4, Count5, endCount3, endCount4, endCount5 As Long
Dim QLRVar As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim IsOffice2013 As Boolean: IsOffice2013 = False
Dim IsOffice2010 As Boolean: IsOffice2010 = False
```

How the Word doc is opened / recalled

```
On Error Resume Next
Set wrdApp = GetObject(Class:="Word.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If wrdApp Is Nothing Then
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApp.Visible = True
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add
Else:
    wrdApp.Visible = True
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add
End If
```

Section with the error

```
With wrdApp.ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
    .NumberFormat = "%1. "
    .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
    .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
    .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0)
    .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
    .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0)
    .TabPosition = wdUndefined
    .ResetOnHigher = 0
    .StartAt = 1
    .LinkedStyle = "Heading 0"
End With
```

Error is on the .NumberPosition line.

The macro is very large so I'm posting what I think are the relevant parts but I'll add more if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft says you must fully qualify every reference, See:
[Microsoft error explanation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/178510/excel-automation-fails-second-time-code-runs)

I have added these references as the "Word." additions below to your code:

```
With wrdApp.ListGalleries(Word.wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
    .NumberFormat = "%1. "
    .TrailingCharacter = Word.wdTrailingTab
    .NumberStyle = Word.wdListNumberStyleArabic
    .NumberPosition = Word.InchesToPoints(0)
    .Alignment = Word.wdListLevelAlignLeft
    .TextPosition = Word.InchesToPoints(0)
    .TabPosition = Word.wdUndefined
    .ResetOnHigher = 0
    .StartAt = 1
    .LinkedStyle = "Heading 0"
End With
```

I can't remember if InchesToPoints() is a Word function, but I have guessed that it is. I hope you get the idea.

Check the rest of your code too. Any non-qualified reference could trigger this error. Check every referenced library (e.g. Outlook, Excel, ADODB, etc.)

Good luck finding them all. This error is a beast in large code blocks. I don't know of a way to find the one reference that I invariably miss. If anyone else knows, please share.

Let us all know how you make out. We all need to share what works and what doesn't.

Comment: It looks like the my example code of "Word.InchesToPoints(0)" above should be "wrdApp.InchesToPoints(0)" to reference your active object.