# "Run-time error 92: For loop not initialized" Error after the first successful run

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, ms-word, runtime-error

I am supposed to revise a tool of a former colleague. This creates a Word document based on an Excel table (column 1 = heading, column 2 = text). The Excel table should be expandable in the long run. Which chapters are created can be selected by check boxes.
However, if the tool is used more than once, the run time error 92 occurs. Since I use a mask with data that is also inserted in the document, the tool should not have to be restarted. I am a complete beginner and would be very happy about a tip. After the For-loop is a block that formats the headings. Maybe this is also where the error lies.
Many thanks in advance!

I have seen a similar problem here, unfortunately it did not help me.
[Can't solve Run-time error 92: For loop not initialized. Any idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55257739/cant-solve-run-time-error-92-for-loop-not-initialized-any-idea)

```
With wdApp.Selection
'Text body is created from Excel
Dim oChild As Node
 For Each X In tv_Texte.Nodes
    If X.Checked And X.Children Then
            .InsertBreak 7
            .Style = wddoc.Styles("Überschrift 1")
            .TypeText Text:=X.Text
            .TypeParagraph
            Set oChild = X.Child
            Do
               On Error GoTo Error:
                If oChild.Checked Then
                'Search entry in table
                i = 1
                Do Until IsEmpty(Workbooks(1).Sheets(X.Text).Range("A" & i + 3)) Or (Workbooks(1).Sheets(X.Text).Range("A" & i + 3) = oChild.Text)
                    i = i + 1
                    Loop
                .Style = wddoc.Styles("Überschrift 2")
                .TypeText Text:=oChild.Text
                .TypeParagraph
                .Style = wddoc.Styles("Standard")
                If IsEmpty(Workbooks(1).Sheets(X.Text).Range("B" & i + 3).Value) Then
                       MsgBox "Fehler beim Importieren der Überschrift: " & vbCrLf & X.Text & " -> " & oChild.Text & vbCrLf & "Kein Text hinterlegt!"
                Else
                'Insert chapter text
                wdApp.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify
                .TypeText Text:=Replace(Workbooks(1).Sheets(X.Text).Range("B" & i + 3).Value, "vbTab", vbTab)
                .TypeParagraph
                End If
                End If
                Set oChild = oChild.Next
Error:
            Loop Until oChild Is Nothing
   
    End If
Next X
'This block creates the headings:
With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
        .NumberFormat = "%1"
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
        .NumberPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0.76)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 0
        .StartAt = 1
        .LinkedStyle = "Überschrift 1"
End With
With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(2)
        .NumberFormat = "%1.%2"
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
        .NumberPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = CentimetersToPoints(1.02)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 1
        .StartAt = 1
        .LinkedStyle = "Überschrift 2"
End With
With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(3)
        .NumberFormat = "%1.%2.%3"
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
        .NumberPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 2
        .StartAt = 1
        .LinkedStyle = "Überschrift 3"
End With
With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(4)
        .NumberFormat = "%1.%2.%3.%4"
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
        .NumberPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = CentimetersToPoints(1.52)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 3
        .StartAt = 1
        .LinkedStyle = "Überschrift 4"
End With
With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(5)
        .NumberFormat = "%1.%2.%3.%4.%5"
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
        .NumberPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = CentimetersToPoints(1.78)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 4
        .StartAt = 1
        .LinkedStyle = "Überschrift 5"
End With
With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(6)
        .NumberFormat = "%1.%2.%3.%4.%5.%6"
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
        .NumberPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = CentimetersToPoints(2.03)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 5
        .StartAt = 1
        .LinkedStyle = "Überschrift 6"
End With
With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(7)
        .NumberFormat = "%1.%2.%3.%4.%5.%6.%7"
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
        .NumberPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = CentimetersToPoints(2.29)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 6
        .StartAt = 1
        .LinkedStyle = "Überschrift 7"
End With
With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(8)
        .NumberFormat = "%1.%2.%3.%4.%5.%6.%7.%8"
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
        .NumberPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = CentimetersToPoints(2.54)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 7
        .StartAt = 1
        .LinkedStyle = "Überschrift 8"
End With
With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(9)
        .NumberFormat = "%1.%2.%3.%4.%5.%6.%7.%8.%9"
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
        .NumberPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = CentimetersToPoints(2.79)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 8
        .StartAt = 1
        .LinkedStyle = "Überschrift 9"
End With
        ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).Name = ""
        .Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
        ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), _
        ContinuePreviousList:=False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, _
        DefaultListBehavior:=wdWord10ListBehavior
        .Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1         'Empty chapter is created and deleted
End With
```

Comment: Your first task is to comment out the 'on error' statementt and tto report tthe actual lie on which the error occurs.

Comment: Welcome to SO. According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-loop-not-initialized-error-92) probably the problem is your labels. Actually you are using `On Error GoTo Error` but you never deactivate it. Actually the answer you linked explain what you need

Comment: Thx for your fast answers.
The error appears at `Next X`.
I tried to use the method in the link, but maybe did something else wrong. I will try it again.

Comment: Try putting an On Error Goto 0 after the Next X.  Currently your on error statement will cause an error in the code after the Next x to jump back to the error label. (inside the for loop) after the for loop has completed.

Comment: @freeflow the `On Error GoTo 0` worked, there is no more Error 92. Thank you for that. I can create as much word files as I want BUT if I close all word files and try to create another one, there will be "Run-time error 462 : The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable". But there are existing questions about this, so I will try to get a solution by myself first.

Comment: Great Stuff.  I put my comment as the answer, please selectt it as the correct answer.

Comment: If someone ist following this, the solution to the new errror "Run-time error 462 : The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable" is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36796186/excel-2010-vba-runtime-error-462-the-remote-server-machine-does-not-exist-or-is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting an On Error Goto 0 after the Next X. Currently your on error statement will cause an error in the code after the Next x to jump back to the error label. (inside the for loop) after the for loop has completed.